# Cannot find id of control inside gridview which inside another gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me on this? 
I have a button(ImageButton1) inside a GridView (gvSdt), and gridview b is inside another Gridview (gvClass). 
but it come out an error said "The name 'gvSdt' does not exist in the current context"
The code i used as below:

```
protected void gvSdt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvSdt.SelectedRow;
    int rowIndex = gvSdt.SelectedIndex;
    string strValue = gvSdt.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is Gridview named **gvSdt** inside Gridview named **gvClass**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `gvSdt` is contained within another GridView, you won't be able to access it directly, as it is repeated content. Since `gvSdt` can exist multiple times, `gvSdt` would therefore refer to multiple GridViews.

This is made easy however, since you are using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the GridView in question. Notice the `sender` argument of the method. The object that gets passed there is actually the GridView. So just cast it as such.

```
protected void gvSdt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvSdt = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow row = gvSdt.SelectedRow;
    int rowIndex = gvSdt.SelectedIndex;
    string strValue = gvSdt.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```